# type specific behavior inside a generic function

Tags: c#, generics

I have

```
T? Get(string key) where T : struct {}
```

I want to provide specific behavior for a specific type. I expect to be able to do one of 2 things. First add a new function

```
 T? Get(string key) where T : DateTimeOffset {}
```

this doesnt work, the syntax is simply invalid. So the other choice is add conditional logic in the function like this:

```
   if(typeof(T) == typeof(DateTimeOffset))
    {
        return DateTimeOffset.Parse(massaged);
    }
```

this doesn't work because I end up trying to return something that isn't generically T , its DateTimeOffset.

I know I could add a different method `GetDateTimeOffset` but I am trying to create a uniform interface.

Any Ideas?

I know its got to be doable - imagine the code inside newtonsoft's (truly wonderful) `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` it has got to be crammed with this type of conditional code. I suppose I should go read that code

Comment: Does `return (T)DateTimeOffset.Parse(massaged);` work?

Comment: no - nor does (T?)DateTimeOffset.....

Comment: Hmm. The compiler cannot know how to convert `DateTimeOffset` to any struct, and there's no way to tell it "in this case T is DateTimeOffset". I think you could do it with some nasty `Marshal.StructureToPtr`  and `Marshal.PtrToStructure` stuff..

Comment: Ah, maybe not: "Type 'System.DateTimeOffset' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
public T? Get<T>(string key) where T : struct
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTimeOffset))
    {
        var dateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.Parse(key); //or what have you
        return dateTimeOffset as T?;
    }
    return null; //etc.
}
```